# How to track why site crashed in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, crash

I have massive Single Page Application and I'm now starting to see once in a while my site crash. And I don't know how to track why it crashed. No memory leaks as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type in chrome://crashes/ in your browser and from there you should have a link to enable crash reporting.  After that you can use chrome://crashes/ to see crash reports.

Comment: I enabled crash reports but chrome doesn't save those, and I have no clue why.

Comment: It's really hard to help without more information.  Can you give some more information about your application?  What is it? How was it built? Maybe even post your code.